# MySQL slow query that uses the index and isn't slow when I run it through the profiler

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb, database-performance, mysql-slow-query-log

In my slow query log I am seeing slow queries like

```
# Time: 121107 16:34:02
# User@Host: web_node[web_node] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 34436186  Schema: test_db  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 1.413751  Lock_time: 0.000222  Rows_sent: 203  Rows_examined: 203  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 203
# Bytes_sent: 7553  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
# InnoDB_trx_id: 9B04384
SET timestamp=1352334842;
SELECT id, email FROM test_data WHERE id IN (13089576,3002681,3117763,1622233,2941590,12305279,1732672,2446772,3189510,13084725,4943929,5855071,6572137,2266261,3003496,2024860,3336832,13758671,6477694,1796684,13001771,4690025,1071744,1017876,5175795,795988,1619821,2481819,2941090,4770802,13438250,3254708,2323402,526303,13219855,3313573,3190479,1733761,3300577,2941758,6474118,1733379,11523598,4205064,6521805,2492903,1860388,3337093,5205317,1213970,5442738,12194039,1214203,12970536,3076611,3126152,3677156,5305021,2751587,4954875,875480,2105172,5309382,12981920,5204330,13729768,3254503,5030441,2680750,590661,1338572,7272410,1860386,2567550,5434143,1918035,5329411,1683235,3254119,5175784,1855380,3336834,2102567,4749746,37269,3207031,6464336,2227907,2713471,3937600,2940442,2233821,5619141,5204711,5988803,5050821,10109926,5226877,5050275,1874115,13677832,5338699,2423773,6432937,6443660,1990611,6090667,6527411,6568731,3254846,3414049,2011907,5180984,12178711,8558260,3130655,5864745,2059318,3480233,2104948,2387703,1939395,5356002,2681209,1184622,1184456,10390165,510854,7983305,795991,2622393,4490187,9436477,5356051,2423464,5205318,1600499,13623229,3255205,12200483,6477706,3445661,5226284,1176639,13760962,2101681,6022818,12909371,1732457,2377496,7260091,12191702,2492899,2630691,13047691,1684470,9382108,2233737,13117701,1796698,2535914,4941741,4565958,1100410,2321180,13080467,813342,4563877,4689365,2104756,1102802,2714488,3188947,1599770,1558291,5592740,5233428,5204830,1574452,3188956,13693326,2102349,3704111,1748303,790889,9323280,4741494,2387900,5338213,3583795,2283942,3189482,3002296,4490123,3585020,962926,3481423,1600920,1682364,4693123,6487778,2677582,2377195);
```

When I run the slow query through the profiler using SQL_NO_CACHE it looks says

```
203 rows in set (0.03 sec)

show profile for query 33;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000187 |
| checking permissions | 0.000012 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000034 |
| System lock          | 0.000016 |
| init                 | 0.000087 |
| optimizing           | 0.000024 |
| statistics           | 0.028694 |
| preparing            | 0.000074 |
| executing            | 0.000005 |
| Sending data         | 0.001596 |
| end                  | 0.000009 |
| query end            | 0.000008 |
| closing tables       | 0.000014 |
| freeing items        | 0.001600 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000007 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000011 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

when I run the query with explain it says

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_data        | range | PRIMARY,id_email | id_email | 4       | NULL |  203 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

the create table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `test_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `unistall_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `subscription_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `domain` (`domain`),
  KEY `id_email` (`id`,`email`),
  KEY `email_id` (`email`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13848530 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There is another query that gets run regularly selecting the id and email from a list of email addresses hence the email, id key, the email address need to be unique hence why that is a unique key. The table only has ~14M rows

I thought maybe the indexes where getting to big for memory and swapping but the box has 8 gigs of ram.

```
 SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", SUM( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024   "Data Base Size in MB", SUM( index_length) / 1024 / 1024 "Index Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Data Base Name     | Data Base Size in MB | Index Size in MB |
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| metrics            |        3192.50000000 |    1594.42187500 |
| data               |        8096.48437500 |    5639.51562500 |
| raw_data           |        6000.35937500 |     745.07812500 |
| information_schema |           0.00878906 |       0.00878906 |
| mysql              |           0.04319191 |       0.04101563 |
| performance_schema |           0.00000000 |       0.00000000 |
+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Setting innodb_file_per_table=1 in the my.cnf file appears to have solved the issue.

This improved the execution time, my understanding is that having the single file per table means that the disk needle doesn't need to move such large distances.

**Questions**

1. If the query can be evaluated using the indexes why does setting innodb_file_per_table=1 improve the performance
2. Why isnt the query slow when it is run for the profiler without using the cache?
3. Should my primary key be (id, email) ?

**Update**

Originally there was no /etc/my.cnf file then I created one with the following

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1
max_connections=1500
key_buffer_size=50M
query_cache_limit=16M
query_cache_size=256M
thread_cache=16
table_open_cache=4096
sort_buffer_size=512K
join_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=8M
skip_name_resolve=1
thread_cache_size=256
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
innodb_thread_concurrency=96
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=32M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table=1
net_read_timeout=15
net_write_timeout=30
log-bin=mysql-bin
sync_binlog=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too much data for your innodb_log_buffer.

What are the values of:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size 
innodb_log_file_size
```

All of InnoDB must run in memory.  When you split up the files it is running more efficiently because it is swapping in and out of memory with less disk reads and writes as one larger file takes longer to scan for the data.

Its not swapping because your innodb_buffer_pool_size is constraining the amount of memory that MySQL loads into memory.

The only way to fix your problem is get more memory and allocate enough innodb_buffer_pool_size for all of your innodb tables and indexes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation I updated the original question with the answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah - innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G - your data will not fit in that.  You have 16.8GB of data+index.  If you can increase memory, that is your best bet, otherwise, I would consider moving some data to an ARCHIVE table.